# Eclipse's "variable references non-existent source: ${workspace_loc:project/project.py}" error

Tags: python, eclipse

[The screenshot I took of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlupT.png)
[image]

Recently, Eclipse has been showing me this error message that basically says I'm referencing to a non-existent source: `${workspace_loc:project/project.py}` every time I try to compile anything. I tried Debugging and it worked, but I was just wondering if there is a permanent fix to this problem, or if I am doing something incorrectly, since I am new to programming.

Thank you.

Comment: Does a leading slash (`${workspace_loc:/project/project.py}`) fix this issue?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused - I don't recall having that whole line anywhere in my code.

Comment: If you do not find the variable in the launch/run/debug configuration (_Run > Run Configurations..._), in the _Navigator_ view open the `.project` file and add the content of this file to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a project with name "project.py"?

Check your resources Location and give the path correctly to your project where the files are located